# Adding custom attribute to openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am attempting to setup [ConTagged - The LDAP Address Book](http://www.cosmocode.de/en/opensource/contagged) but I am having a few issues with some of the attributes. The problem is that some of them are undefined and they do not seem to be in the inetorgperson.schema. How do I set these custom attributes?

For reference, here is the exact error I receive whenever I make a change to a contact.

```
The LDAP server returned the following errors
Invalid syntax
Undefined attribute type(del anniversary)
Undefined attribute type(del marker)
Object class violation(mod c)
Undefined attribute type(del custom1)
Undefined attribute type(del custom2)
Undefined attribute type(del custom3)
Undefined attribute type(del custom4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [readme](https://github.com/cosmocode/contagged/blob/master/doc/README) has instructions for adding these attributes. You need to save [`ldapab.schema`](https://github.com/cosmocode/contagged/blob/master/doc/ldapab.schema) on the server and include it in `slapd.conf`:

```
include /etc/ldap/schema/ldapab.schema
```

Comment: Thanks for that response, I must have just skimmed over that line and did not see it. Hah oh well, we're all not good readers! :)